# Random colored Text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to type a block of text into a div and have every word separated by a space, and/or comma be a different color of the rainbow, except for black or white. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you typing into a contenteditable?

Comment: @box9: uhhh...not sure. Its not to be editable by viewers if thats what your asking. Most that will happen is each block of text will be a link. Thats about it.

Comment: You want to type as in literally? Or does the DIV have predefined text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that you're asking for "colours of the rainbow", you probably don't want to generate truly random colours (you'll get dull colours and greys as well). You can set up an array with the set of colours you'd like to use, and randomly assign those:

```
// any valid css colours
var colors = ["#ff3322", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

$('#someText').html(function (i, text) {
    return $.map(text.split(' '), function (word) {
         return '<span style="color:'
             + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
             + '">' + word + '</span>';
    }).join(' ');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bjGEF/

Comment: it doesn't work. `$.map` already returns an `Array`, you cannot apply `.get()` on that.

Comment: @jAndy, thanks I just noticed. Serves me right for not testing it. Working now, with jsfiddle to boot!

Comment: do any of you think you can give me assistance on this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789980/load-external-page-into-a-div-from-table-row-click

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($) {
    function rndcol() {
        return [~~(Math.random()*255), ~~(Math.random()*255), ~~(Math.random()*255)];
    }

    $.fn.colorize = function() {
        return this.each(function(i,e) {
            $(this).html(function(index, text) {
               return $.map(text.split(' '), function(word, index) {
                   return "<span style='color: rgb(" + rndcol().join(',') + ")'>" + word + "</span>";
               }).join(' ');
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));


$('someelement').colorize();
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ny5Ve/1/

To have every `character` colorized, you just need to replace the whitespace characters in `.split()` and `.join()` with nothing ("").

Comment: That `~~` is very sexy. More information here http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/ for those interested.

Comment: or here: http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2010/11/about-javascript-shortcuts-trickery.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 <sctipt>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var sps = "";
    var texts = $('.div').html().split(" ");
    var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];
    texts.each(function(t,i){
      var rand   = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
        sps += "<span style='color:"+rand+"'>"+t+"</span>";
    });
    $('.div').html(sps);
});
</script>
```